# Power BI DAX Error: Column "WeeksOnsite' in table 'Timelogs' cannot be found or may be used in this expression

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
CountEmployeesOnsiteAtLeast2WeeksPerMonth =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                FILTER ( Table1, 'Table1'[Log Type] = "Time-In" ),
                "SummarizedMonth", RELATED ( 'Date'[Month] ),
                "Employees", 'Table1'[Employee Name],
                "WeeksOnsite", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Timelogs' ), 'Timelogs'[is_Onsite] >= 3 )
            ),
            [SummarizedMonth],
            [Employees],
            "Total Weeks Onsite", SUM ( 'Table1'[WeeksOnsite] )
        ),
        [Total Weeks Onsite] >= 2
    )
)
```

I am trying to count the number of employees who works onsite at least 2 weeks in a month. The criteria to be tagged as Onsite is an employee should work onsite for at least 3 days a week to be tagged as Onsite.

Can someone enlighten me how to debug this code please.

I tried to summarize the table first by month and weeks, and count the number of onsite an employee took.

I created a column [is_Onsite] that tagged 1 if Onsite and 0 for Remote Work.
I counted the onsite per week (>= 3 days)
Then proceed to summarize by month hoping that It will count the number of onsite week. But I failed. Can someone please enlighten me workaround to make this work. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think `SUMMARIZE` likes being used over a table statement using `ADDCOLUMNS`. You can probably rewrite your expression to not use this, but to get help with this you need to post some sample data and information about what your data model looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping 'Table1' so you have `"Total Weeks Onsite", SUM ( [WeeksOnsite] )`